# the `locate` command (Linux) doesn't show any files in homedirectory

Tags: linux, locate

System: Debian Sid

Problem: The `locate` command only returns files that exist outside my (the user's) home directory. This behaviour is new and was probably introduced through some package upgrade.

The command behaved normal and returned the names of files and directories from anywhere on the system, but is now somehow limited as described.

I guess this has to do with the database and maybe with `updatedb`, but I'm not familiar with the setup. 
What can I check and change in order to restore normal behaviour of `locate`?

Answer (score 2):

The `locate` command uses the database prepared over-night by `updatedb`.
Your problem is that for privacy concerns, by default `updatedb` does not
scan directories that are not *readable by every user*.

If you want to create a database only for yourself you can use:

```
updatedb -l 0  --output=/home/username/.mydb.db
```

And to search within it using:

```
locate -d ~/.mydb.db search-pattern
```

You may use aliases to make it more convenient:

```
alias lupdatedb="updatedb -l 0  --output=/home/username/.mydb.db"
alias llocate="locate -d ~/.mydb.db"
```

However, as `locate` will not find new files without running `updatedb` first,
I would think that the `find` command would be more useful, as it scans
the real files rather than an outdated database.